# Get link depending on selected language in Docusaurus

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I have activated `i18n` on the website generated with Docusaurus. How can I get the internal link depending on the user's language on GUI?

E.g. I would like to navigate to `/docs` when the button is clicked. If the default language `en` is active, then it should return `/docs`, but in the case of `fr` it must return `/fr/docs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting link depending on selected language one can use docusaurus `useBaseUrl` Hook, which prepend sites `baseUrl` to string (i.e. link). E.g.:

```js
import useBaseUrl from '@docusaurus/useBaseUrl';
...
// if e.g. fr selected i18nLink="/fr/docs", otherwise i18nLink="/docs"
const i18nLink = useBaseUrl('docs');
```